# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values' explored the existing solutions

Tags: python

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-113-4215b6c9f2c9> in <module>
      7     #kfold  = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, random_state=2, test_size=.25)
      8     #kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=3,shuffle=True )
----> 9     cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train.values.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
     10     results.append(cv_results)
     11     names.append(name)
```

```
for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train.values.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Comment: What is the dype of `Y_train` can you print and post the output for `type(Y_train)`? As the error suggests, `Y_train` seems to be a numpy array, but you are using `Y_train.values`, which is a pandas method for getting a numpy array from a given dataframe/series.